# Multi-select / modify event Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, geometry, modify-interaction

I'm trying to incorporate a modify feature where the user will move a point and any underlying geometry is also modified. Currently to draw a route on a map I'm taking points from a database and creating a Feature for each(ol.geom.Point) and then pushing the same coordinates into an array for the underlying linestring. All of these are added to a Feature Collection so if there were 28 points in the database, there will be a feature collection with 29 items(28 points and a linestring).

The Select and Modify interactions are set to multi:true and this seems to occasionally allow me to select both the waypoint and the vertex point beneath but it's really hit and miss.

These are sample Modify Start/End functions:

```
session.interactions.modify.on('modifystart', function (e) {
        session.selectedFeatures = session.activeRoute.Layers[0].getSource().getFeatures();
        session.testArray = e.features.getArray();
        for (var p = 0; p < session.testArray.length; p++) {
             session.modifiedGuid = session.testArray[p].get('Guid');
             session.originalCoordinates = session.testArray[p].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                }
  });

  session.interactions.modify.on('modifyend', function (e) {
         session.selectedFeatures = session.activeRoute.Layers[0].getSource().getFeatures();
         var lsRoute = session.selectedFeatures[session.selectedFeatures.length - 1];
         console.log(lsRoute);
         console.log(lsRoute.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
         console.log(session.testArray);
                for (var p = 0; p < session.testArray.length; p++) {
                    console.log(session.testArray[p].get('Guid'));
             console.log(session.testArray[p].getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                    session.modifiedCoordinates = session.testArray[p].getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                    updateModifiedGeom(session.modifiedGuid, session.originalCoordinates, session.modifiedCoordinates);
                }
            });
```

The updateModifiedGeom function was logging to the console the Guid, original, and modified coordinates but since I specified multi: true on the modify interaction it's no longer picking up these details, only the linestring array beneath.

I'm sorry if this seems a little garbled but I've been struggling for months to be able to display rich data points on a linestring and this is the only way I've been able to resolve it to any degree.

I'd previously [posted this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179574/bind-vector-geometry-to-viewmodel-or-how-to-keep-track-of-modified-points) which received no responses and I've managed to get this far but hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong. I can't post a fiddle as it would take far too long to adapt the code to work in a stand-alone way.